# how to do a reverse explode transition animation in android in grid recyclerview

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions

I have posted my code for exploding content in grid recyclerview in android using transition animation. how to achieve reverse explode like when i enter the ExplodeAnimationActivity all the items in the recyclerview should come inn reverse of explode.

[image]

```
public class ExplodeAnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String android_version_names[] = {
        "Donut",
        "Eclair",
        "Froyo",
        "Gingerbread",
        "Honeycomb",
        "Ice Cream Sandwich",
        "Jelly Bean",
        "KitKat",
        "Lollipop",
        "Marshmallow"
};

private final String android_image_urls[] = {
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/eclair.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/froyo.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/ginger.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/honey.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/icecream.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/jellybean.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/kitkat.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/lollipop.png",
        "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/marshmallow.png"
};

RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animations);
    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList<AndroidVersion> androidVersions = prepareData();
    ExplodeAnimationAdapter adapter = new ExplodeAnimationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), androidVersions);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // save rect of view in screen coordinates
            final Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);

            // create Explode transition with epicenter
            Transition explode = new Explode();
            explode.setEpicenterCallback(new Transition.EpicenterCallback() {
                @Override
                public Rect onGetEpicenter(Transition transition) {
                    return viewRect;
                }
            });
            explode.setDuration(1000);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView, explode);

            // remove all views from Recycler View
            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
 private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> prepareData() {

    ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_version = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < android_version_names.length; i++) {
        AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
        androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(android_version_names[i]);
        androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
        android_version.add(androidVersion);
    }
    return android_version;
}
}
```

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html. It explains various animations provided by android.

Comment: @Hari_krish4 i have checked this already but i dint find animation for reverse explode documentation. thanks for reply

Comment: Hi @YLS did you find anything for this

Comment: @Smith not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, maybe you have found the answer yourself. I tried the same example like you with some changes and was able to revers the transition just by setting the Transition mode. I haven´t done it with recycler view, but it should work too.

```
private Explode makeInExplodeTransition() {
    Explode explode = new Explode();
    explode.setDuration(3000);
    explode.setMode(Visibility.MODE_OUT); 
    explode.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    return explode;
}
```

If your transition should be reversed, the following change works:

```
explode.setMode(Visibility.MODE_IN);
```

In my case, it looked that it didn´t work. I started the activity and directly the animation and the views were there without animation. So I started the animation with a delay. I think the problem is that the animation is finished before the activity is full visible, maybe a thing of some milliseconds.